# Fill in blank dates for rolling average - CTE in Snowflake

Tags: sql, count, common-table-expression, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, recursive-query

I have two tables – `activity` and `purchase`

Activity table:

```
user_id     date      videos_watched
   1     2020-01-02        3
   1     2020-01-04        5
   1     2020-01-07        5
```

Purchase table:

```
user_id  purchase_date 
   1       2020-01-01 
   2       2020-02-02
```

What I would like to do is to get a 30 day rolling average since purchase on how many videos has been watched.

The base query is like this:

```sql
    SELECT
    DATEDIFF(DAY, p.purchase_date, a.date) AS day_since_purchase,
    AVG(A.VIDEOS_VIEWED)
    FROM PURCHASE P
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ACTIVITY A ON P.USER_ID = A.USER_ID AND
        A.DATE >= P.PURCHASE_DATE AND A.DATE <= DATEADD(DAY, 30, P.PURCHASE_DATE)
    GROUP BY 1;
```

However, the `Activity` table only has records for each day a video has been logged. I would like to *fill in the blanks* for days a video has not been viewed.

I have started to look into using a `CTE` like this:

```sql
    WITH cte AS (
        SELECT date('2020-01-01') as fdate
        UNION ALL
        SELECT CAST(DATEADD(day,1,fdate) as date)
    FROM cte
    WHERE fdate < date('2020-04-01')
    ) select * from cte 
      cross join purchases p
      left outer join activity a 
      on p.user id = a.user_id 
      and a.fdate = p.purchase_date
      and a.date >= p.purchase_date and a.date <= dateadd(day, 30, p.purchase_date)
```

The end goal is to have something like this:

```
days_since_purchase    videos_watched
        1                   3
        2                   0 --CTE coalesce inserted value
        3                   0
        4                   5
```

Been trying for the last couple of hours to get it right, but still can't really get the hang of it.

Comment: Purchases aren't all going to have the same dates, correct?

Comment: Correct, they will be on different days within a month (hence the rolling average)

Comment: And I just saw the example table as well. So clearly that fixed set of dates isn't going to work either. I think something like Gordon's answer is what you want. The other big difference is noting the order that the joins appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fill in the gaps in the result set, then I think you should be generating integers rather than dates:

```
WITH cte AS (
      SELECT 1 as day_since_purchase
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 + day_since_purchase
      FROM cte
      WHERE day_since_purchase < 4
     )
SELECT cte.day_since_purchase, COALESCE(avg_videos_viewed, 0)
FROM cte LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, p.purchase_date, a.date) AS day_since_purchase,
             AVG(A.VIDEOS_VIEWED) as avg_videos_viewed
      FROM purchases p JOIN
           activity a 
           ON p.user id = a.user_id AND
              a.fdate = p.purchase_date AND
              a.date >= p.purchase_date AND
              a.date <= dateadd(day, 30, p.purchase_date)
      GROUP BY 1
     ) pa
     ON pa.day_since_purchase = cte.day_since_purchase;
```

Comment: Wow, it makes so much more sense to use integers rather than the actual dates (ran in to problems with the min/max-dates being fixed and the averages rolling). Seems to be working quite well, many thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive query to generate the 30 days following each purchase, then bring the activity table:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        purchase_date,
        client_id,
        0 days_since_purchase,
        purchase_date dt
    from purchases 
    union all
    select 
        purchase_date,
        client_id,
        days_since_purchase + 1
        dateadd(day, days_since_purchase + 1, purchase_date)
    from cte
    where days_since_purchase < 30

)
select 
    c.days_since_purchase,
    avg(colaesce(a. videos_watch, 0)) avg_ videos_watch
from cte c
left join activity a
    on  a.client_id = c.client_id
    and a.fdate = c.purchase_date
    and a.date = c.dt
group by c.days_since_purchase
```

Your question is unclear on whether you have a column in the `activity` table that stores the purchase date each row relates to. Your query has column `fdate` but not your sample data. I used that column in the query (without such column, you might end up counting the same activity in different purchases).

Comment: Ah sorry for the confusion. The `fdate` was in reference to the `CTE` and not any actual column in the tables. There is no reference to the purchase date in the `activity` table, only the `user_id` to look it up through the purchase table.

Comment: @user2868900: if so you can just remove the corresponding join condition: `and a.fdate = c.purchase_date`